# ¿como se puede obtener la cantidad de coincidencias en una consulta mysql con left join?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo en una base de datos una tabla donde se registran los inicios de sesión de cada usuario, y otra donde almaceno las modificaciones que hace en el sistema el mismo usuario.
En caso dado de que el usuario no realice ninguna modificación en el sistema, no se guardara nada en la tabla de las modificaciones.

Necesito imprimir una lista en html donde cada `<li></li>` sea un inicio de sesióny solo si en la sesión se realizaron cambios incrustar un `<ul><ul>` donde estaran todas las modifcaciones correspondientes a esa sesión.

Por ejemplo:

```
<ul>
 <li>27-02-2017</li>
 <li>28-02-2017
     <ul>
         <li>Creo usuario nuevo</li>
         <li>Cambio departamento a usuario</li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li>01-09-2017
     <ul>
         <li>Elimino usuario</li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li>02-02-2018</li>
```

y en php lo que tengo es algo así

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT a.field1, a.field2, b.field3, b.field4 from tabla_a a left join tabla_b b on a.field1 = b.field4";
$query = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
echo "<ul>"
while($inf = mysqli_fetch_array()){
    echo "<li>{$inf["field2"]}</li>"
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Lo que no sé es como hacer que si el numero de coincidencias con left join es igual o mayor a 1 inserte el `<ul></ul>`, se me ocurria hacer una consulta dentro de la primer consulta pero seria demasiado lenta la respuesta.

¿Alguna sugerencia?, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que mantener una variable con el valor del *field1* para saber cuando cambia de valor. Además hay que verificar si *field4* tiene un valor para saber si hay que agregar otro **li** dentro de un **ul**. La consulta debe estar ordenada por *field1* para no saltear datos.

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT a.field1, a.field2, b.field3, b.field4 from tabla_a a left join tabla_b b on a.field1 = b.field4 ORDER BY field1";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    echo "<ul>";
    $pivote = -1;
    $inf = mysqli_fetch_array();
    while($inf){
      if ($pivote != $inf["field1"]){
          echo "<li>{$inf["field2"]}</li>";
          $pivote = $inf["field1"];
      }
      if ($inf["field4"]){
          echo "<lu>";
          do {
              if ($pivote != $inf["field1"]){
                 break;
              }
              echo "<li>{$inf["field3"]}</li>";
          }while ($inf = mysqli_fetch_array());
          echo "</ul>";
      }else{
          $inf = mysqli_fetch_array();
      }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    ?>
```